# LinkedIn API Get Access Token Failed

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

We are trying to implement the LinkedIn API authentication module based on: `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/context`.

We have the redirect url for the application setup as our company's main page (`https://www.{site}.com`) and we are able to get the auth code from the redirect URL. However, it gives us 401 error below when exchange for access token:

```
b'{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Unable to retrieve 
access token: authorization code not found"}'
```

The weird thing is, it works and we are able to exchange the code for access token if we switch the redirect url to a different site like `https://www.example.com` in the API Console. Below is the Py3 code we use:

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from requests_oauthlib.compliance_fixes import linkedin_compliance_fix

# Credentials and redirect uri you get from registering a new application
client_id = 'client_id'
client_secret = 'client_secret'
redirect_url = 'redirect_url'


# OAuth endpoints given in the LinkedIn API documentation (check for updates)
authorization_base_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization'
token_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken'

# Authorized Redirect URL (from LinkedIn config)
o2_session = OAuth2Session(client_id=client_id, redirect_uri=redirect_url, scope=['rw_ads', 'r_ads_reporting'])
linkedin = linkedin_compliance_fix(o2_session)

# Redirect user to LinkedIn for authorization
authorization_url, state = linkedin.authorization_url(authorization_base_url)

print('Please go here and authorize,', authorization_url)

# Get the authorization verifier code from the callback url
redirect_response = input('Paste the full redirect URL here:')
linkedin.fetch_token(token_url, include_client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret, authorization_response=redirect_response)
token = linkedin.access_token
```

Understood that the auth code has short life span, so tried both redirect URL seconds after the code is post back to the URL. Can anyone think of any reason could cause this weird different behaviors for different redirect URLs.

Comment: Just to let you know I had a similar problem and in my case, I was copying/pasting the code value directly from the callback URL and I did not notice that the end of my URL had a state field, so I was copying/pasting the hole value and not only the code value. 

My URL was:
mycallbackurl.com/?code=MY_BIG_URL_TOKEN&state=secret178189

Comment: My god I feel so dumb... thanks dude!!!!